# I am developing an application using google places api. Is check-ins to a place are per application

Tags: google-places-api

As per google places API documentation, no authentication is required for using the API. Is that how even check-ins to a place works? number of check-ins to a place are application dependent or aggregation of all check-ins across all registered apps.

Why checks-ins API is not provided via [Google Places Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

Comment: @Shenaniganz confused by the API or with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Google Places API requires you to authenticate each request using an API Key.

Any Places API Check-In Requests sent using the Places API will only affect subsequent Places API Search Request for the API Key used to issue the Check-Ins.

As the Places Library of the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 does not require authentication to use, Check-Ins are not part of the library.